# how to Install a python project into multiple directories

Tags: python, setuptools

Using setuptools I am able to get python to install in the /opt/ directory but I would also like to specify a single file to be installed in the /usr/bin directory.

Example tree:

```
setup.py
src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    main.py
```

Currently I am using the following command

```
python setup.py install --install-lib=/opt/src
```

to get the following installed.

```
opt/src/
    file1.py
    file2.py
    main.py
```

but I would like it to be installed as below.

```
/opt/src/
    file1.py
    file2.py

/usr/bin/
    main.py
```

Comment: The setuptools [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) option might help. However, this option is usually frowned upon due to [inconsistency across tools](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2874#issuecomment-109429489) and the difficulty of configuring this option.

Comment: To install into `bin` you can declare `main.py` to be an item of `scripts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install into `bin` you can declare `main.py` to be a script:

```
setup(
    …
    scripts=["main.py"],
    …
)
```